# Gmail POP3 Error

Tags: pop3

I am using POP3 to get my Exchange/Outlook email into Gmail.

Whenever Gmail attempts to receive mail, the following error occurs:

Error: Server is temporarily unavailable. Mail cannot be retrieved from this account at this time.

With the following details:
Server returned error "Error in RETR command: Message corrupted"

However, the mail does seem to be downloaded correctly - and when I run the Exchange health analyzer, it says that my POP3 is setup correctly.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an email is corrupted on the server.  It will skip this email and give this message.  Does it tell you which email it is?  Can you delete it from the server?

Comment: It doesn't say which email is corrupted - I also tried deleting all lingering emails from the account on the server - I am still getting the same message.

Comment: Did you check all folders?  Sent items, Drafts, etc.?

Comment: Of course - I deleted all of the calendar, items, contacts, and tasks as well -

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is hanging up.  The message just means that it is trying to retrieve something and failing.  Short of using a debugger, I'm not sure what else to check.  Using fetchmail on the command line with -vvv should do it.

Comment: I figured it out - I had the gmail in as an alias for the mail user - when I removed it, gmail started being able to download via POP3 without any issues - I'm not sure why this would cause an issue from the Gmail side - but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my GMail for fetching outlook.com POP3. I re-entered correct password of my outlook.com account and GMail started working again.

(Strange that I just corrected the outlook.com account a few weeks ago.)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to skip the corrupt mail:

> Set fetch mail of last 30 days (90 days...) on POP setting of Exchange/Outlook email

After that my gmail fetched successfully.

Comment: How do you do that? I have looked but can't find such an option.